# Maui iOS app, can't fine ViewModels from MainPage.xaml.cs or MauiProgram.cs even though they are there and being referenced

Tags: c#, ios, maui

I have a project structure that looks like this;

[image]

Currently I am working on the iOS piece and have run into a snag. As you can see the Views and ViewModels are at the same level and all is well, however, when trying to reference a ViewModel from MainPage or MauiProgram, both of those give me errors;

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MainMenuViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ViewModels' does not exist in the namespace 'MauiAppSAH.Platforms.iOS' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Each class in the ViewModels directory has this for a namespace;
namespace MauiAppSAH.Platforms.iOS.ViewModels
And everything referencing a ViewModel has a using statement pointing to that namespace.

[image]

Comment: `Views` and `ViewModels` are (generally) shared cross-platform, and should not be placed in platform specific folders

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you! I will make that change, but the question still remains, why can I not get to the ViewModels from the root of the site, the MainPage.xaml.cs and the MauiProgram?

Comment: Did you move those files to the correct location?  Did you check all the namespaces?

Comment: Yes I did and that is all working now, I am just confused as to why I was getting that issue before and would like to know for the future. It doesn't make any sense to me, so I need to understand.

Comment: because if your shared code has a dependency on iOS specific code, then it would break on every other platform.  MAUI has specific ways to access platform specific libraries from shared code